# Node.js Webrtc Audio issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, webrtc

I'm creating an chat application of 3 people using webrtc in node.js.
everything works fine.Audio work perfectly with 2 clients . but when 3rd person joins, 2nd client can't hear the voice of third client. i have muted the localvideo .but still problem occur.any help ?

This is where i get stream of local connection

```
 getUserMedia({
    audio: {echoCancellation: true,sampleRate:44000, sampleSize: 8, 
    channelCount:{ideal: 2, min: 1}, volume: 1.0 },
    video: true
  },gotStream
  ,(function(e) {
    alert('getUserMedia() error: ' + e.name);
  }));
  });
```

this is where i get remote stream

```
function gotRemoteStream( e,clientId){
 for (var i = 0; i < remoteVideoSource.length; i++) {
 if(i===0)
      {
      console.log("First video");
      remoteVideo1.srcObject  = remoteVideoSource[i].stream;
      users[clientId].index = 1;
      }
 else{
    console.log("Second video");
    remoteVideo2.srcObject  = remoteVideoSource[i].stream;  
    users[clientId].index = 2;
   }
}}
```

Offer sending at creating connection

```
var offerOptions = {offerToReceiveAudio:1,offerToReceiveVideo: 1};
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Do you have any code you can show us? Please edit your answer and post your code, also describe what you have tried and failed.

Comment: I have muted local video, and add best possible constraint to audio in  gotstream function.